# Netgear WG311 v2 not identified on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have a Netgear WG311 v2 wireless card. It was working fine on vista. Now I have installed Windows 7 and the device is not identified. Device Manager shows it as an Ethernet card. When I update the driver using the list provided with the Windows distribution. It shows it under Wireless devices in Device Manager but it says device cannot start code 10.

Any idea on how to install it.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the WG311 v2 was simply incompatible with Windows 7. Sorry!

I spent nearly 2 weeks trying different drivers and had no luck whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by running the setup in compatibility mode for windows XP.